# ng-bind-html not working inside partial

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I am using ng-view to load in partials on my angularjs website.  I have been wrestling with a trivial feature which is to add in html to a partial dynamically from a JSON file.  For some reason, I can't get the HTML to render as HTML as opposed to a string.

Code: app.js

```
app.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

In partial: job.html (ng-controller is in div wrapping this partial)

```
<div class="grid-block vertical padding-horizontal always-show">
   <div ng-bind-html="jobDescription.content | to_trusted"></div>
</div>
```

In controller:  job.js

```
$http.jsonp("http://example.com/jobDescription")
  .success(function(response){
     var job = response;
     // custom data operations
     // ...
     $scope.jobDescription = job;

});
```

JSON looks like:

```
 { 
    "content": "&lt;div&gt;This is a job.&lt;/div&gt;"
 }
```

Output is always:

```
"<div>This is a job description</div>"
```

I've come across other people having this issue explicitly in partials.  I've seen something about using $viewContentLoaded and .upgradeAllRegistered();

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might be running in issue with concurrency. Maybe `ngBindHtml` is binding the value BEFORE you filter runs.

You could investigate this issue with [priority](http://www.newyyz.com/blog/2014/12/15/understanding-priorities-in-angularjs-directive-definition-objects/) OR you could use a directive instead of a filter to deal with placing HTML in the DOM for you in this way:

```
app.directive('toTrusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return {
        link: function ($scope) {
              $scope.htmlString = $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        },
        template: "<div ng-bind-html="htmlString"></div>"
    };
}]);
```

and use it like this-

```
<div class="grid-block vertical padding-horizontal always-show">
    <div to-trusted="jobDescription.content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is also the behavior if I were to use a function to call the $sce.  I tried this and it didn't work :/